# rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError

Tags: ros2, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

does anybody know how to fix this error message?

```
Failed to find library 'rcl_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError'
  what():  failed to initialize rcl node: type support not from this implementation, at /home/steve/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/rmw_fastrtps_cpp/src/rmw_publisher.cpp:81, at /home/steve/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rcl/rcl/src/rcl/publisher.c:173
```

The exceptions is thrown at this line:

```
auto node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("minimal_publisher");
```

Kind regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318938/rclcpp::exceptions::rclerror/) by [praetorianer777](https://answers.ros.org/users/40523/praetorianer777/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AnandShastry](https://answers.ros.org/users/40681/anandshastry/) on 2019-04-09**:
is your library compiled ? mean do you have rcl_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.so generated?

**Comment by [ananya.muddu](https://answers.ros.org/users/42686/ananya.muddu/) on 2019-06-17**:
Hi, I have the same problem. The library is not compiled. How do I compile it ? I installed ROS2 from sources on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can happen if the library name for building the messages and the package name is different.  To quote Dirk [here](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/issues/441#issuecomment-591025515),

> Atm the generated library for the interfaces must have the basename `${PROJECT_NAME}`.
>
> You have to options:
>
> either rename your interface target to
> just `${PROJECT_NAME}:`

```
rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME} "srv/MySrv.srv")
rosidl_target_interfaces(my_node ${PROJECT_NAME} "rosidl_typesupport_cpp")
```

> or explicitly set the library name:

```
rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}_srv "srv/MySrv.srv" LIBRARY_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2021-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0